# External install for those Android versions that support it, but support for those that don't

Tags: android, installation, android-manifest

Is it possible to allow an app written for Android 1.5 to specify manifest options that were introduced in version 2.2?

In particular, I'd like to allow my application to be installed to external storage for those OS versions that support it, while being able to run on versions prior as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup!  From the Android Dev Guide > App Install Location > [Backward Compatibility section](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity),

> 1. Include the android:installLocation attribute with a value of "auto" or "preferExternal" in the  element.
> 2. Leave your android:minSdkVersion attribute as is (something less than "8") and be certain that your application code uses only APIs compatible with that level.
> 3. In order to compile your application, change your build target to API Level 8. This is necessary because older Android libraries don't understand the android:installLocation attribute and will not compile your application when it's present.